# neo4j registering object into field

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to store an object in a field with Cypher so that the node will return some fields as

```
field.prop.array[0].prop1
field.prop.array[0].prop2
field.prop.array[1].prop1
field.prop2.prop3.prop4
```

and if so: what's the query to do it? (I've been able to store only 1 level deep objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Neo4j property values can be primitives, Strings or arrays of them, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html.

To build up more nested structures you should make them explicit in the graph. A nested property might become a node that connected to the originating node.